# jmeter multi response data used in request

Tags: json, multithreading, jmeter, response

i have a test plan that has many POST calls like

/api/v1/budgets

now each of those call has a response which return a uuid from the data base, i extract that using a json path extractor and save it to a variable

after i'm doing all the post calls, i need to do the same amount of calls but with DELETE and do it with the uuid i got from the response

is there an efficient way to extract those uuid? for now i had to add a json path extractor manually to each call

and after that, is there a way to save them and run on those saved vars in a loop just send the next one each time?

also i'm gonna use multiple users for each thread, so i don't know if jmeter will be able to solve that issue or i need to handle that as well the threads and the users per thread

Answer (score 0):

JMeter provides [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) which can iterate variables having numeric postfix like:

```
uuid_1
uuid_2
uuid_3
etc.
```

So you can store the uuids above way using for example [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function and use single HTTP Request under ForEach Controller in order to delete them.

I would also recommend getting familiarized with [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables) article to learn how to work with compound variables in JMeter scripts.

Comment: thank you for the comment but this is not the scenario that i need
i need to get the value from each api call, and each api call is separate since it sends a different json